# Can the semantics of a numeric hierarchy be faithfully represented in Haskell?

Tags: programming-languages, number-theory, haskell

I am trying to represent a fragment of a number hierarchy using the Haskell concepts of *value*, *type*, and *type class*. I would like the Haskell code to reflect the mathematical semantics $\vdash ((x \in \mathbb{N}) \land (\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}) \Rightarrow (x  \in \mathbb{Q}))$. In words, given that the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers is a subset of the the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers and integers are a subset of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, we can deduce that every natural number is an rational number. I omit the constraint that natural numbers are actually a *proper subset* of integers.

Below is my attempt at relating the math and Haskell semantics. I am unsure whether a class is a set of types as stated by [GAST](https://publikationen.uni-tuebingen.de/xmlui/handle/10900/48061) (Section 3.5) and hence a type can be considered as an element of a class $(T \in TC)$.

[image: Math and Haskell Semantics]
Note it is possible that $V_1=V_2$ (e.g. 1:Nat=1:Int)

Below is my flawed attempt to capture the mathematical meaning using Haskell. 
I am aware that implementing rationals would lead to a situation where rationals were represented by both a type and a type class (not good!). Please note for research purposes I am restricted to only using values, types,and type class. I am not intentionally seeking to impose Object Oriented class semantic on Haskell.

```
data Natural = One | Suc Natural deriving Show
data Integers = Zero | Succ Integers deriving Show

class RationallNumbers x where
  plus::x -> x -> x

instance RationallNumbers Integers where 
 plus  x  Zero = x
 plus  x  (Succ y)  = Succ (plus x  y)

instance RationallNumbers Natural where
 plus  x  One = Suc x
 plus  x  (Suc y)  = Suc (plus x  y) 

twoPlusTwoNat = plus (Suc One)  (Suc One)
twoPlusTwoInt = plus (Succ (Succ Zero))  (Succ (Succ Zero))
```

To sum up my question is:

Can the numeric hierarchy described be represented in Haskell using the semantic concepts  of values, types, and classes?

Related questions: [A mathematical (categorical) description of type classes](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/a-mathematical-categorical-description-of-type-classes), [Is there a model theory for Haskell type classes?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/is-there-a-model-theory-for-haskell-type-classes)

Comment: [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/61495/quinten-lootens) thanks for your solution which I am certain will work. But, I am more concerned with the actual semantics of Haskell types and classes in implementing a hierarchy.

Comment: I am quite familiar with Haskell, but I can't really understand your question. You use $\mathbb Z$ as both a type and a type class, which puzzles me -- even if you say you are aware of that. Perhaps you want _subtypes_, which Haskell does not have. Usually, without subtypes, you use "inclusion" functions to move from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$, so that they can be separate types, but you can still inject the first into the latter when needed.

Comment: [chi](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/43599/chi) is of course correct to point out the strange representation of Integers as both data and class. This is represents my confusion about type classes. Although there is a relation values-to-types and a relation types-to-classes, there is no transitive relation from value-to-class. In short a value can never be an element of a type class i.e. $V \notin TC$.

Comment: I believe that the two solution proposed "inclusion" and "expressions" will allow $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ to be implemented. But without some form of sub-typing it is hard to see how those implementations would satisfy the mathematical semantics.

Comment: [chi](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/43599/chi) I have updated the question based on your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible. However your approach is a good starter but keep in mind to have a functional approach on writing code in Haskell. You can create expressions so you can define and 'override' methods.

As a suggestion I will give a part of code of how such expressions can look like as values and types.

```
data Exp = Lit Value
         | Assign Name Exp
         | Variable Name
         | Apply Exp Exp
         | Assist Name Exp
         | Exp :+:  Exp
         | Exp :-:  Exp
         | Exp :*:  Exp
         | Exp :=:  Exp
         | Exp :==: Exp
         | Exp :/=: Exp
         | Exp :>:  Exp
         | Exp :>=: Exp
         | Exp :<:  Exp
         | Exp :<=: Exp
         | Exp :&&: Exp
         | Exp :||: Exp
         deriving (Show)
```

This is some code out of a language I've written for controlling micro-controllers. The evaluation can be done as following:

```
-------------------------------------------------
-- Evaluate Expressions Utilities
-------------------------------------------------
-- Evaluate Integer Arithmetic operations
evalInt :: KDLMap -> Exp -> Int
evalInt _ (Lit n)          =  kdlintToInt n
evalInt k (Variable n)     =  kdlintToInt $ searchVariable' n k
evalInt k (e :+: f)        =  evalInt k e + evalInt k f
evalInt k (e :*: f)        =  evalInt k e * evalInt k f
evalInt k (e :-: f)        =  evalInt k e - evalInt k f
evalInt _ _                =  Prelude.error "Unable to perform operation."

-- Evaluate Boolean operations with Integers
evalIntBool :: KDLMap -> Exp -> Bool
evalIntBool k (e :<:   f)         =  evalInt k e <  evalInt k f
evalIntBool k (e :>:   f)         =  evalInt k e >  evalInt k f
evalIntBool k (e :<=:  f)         =  evalInt k e <= evalInt k f
evalIntBool k (e :>=:  f)         =  evalInt k e >= evalInt k f
evalIntBool k (e :/=:  f)         =  evalInt k e /= evalInt k f
evalIntBool k (e :==:  f)         =  evalInt k e == evalInt k f
evalIntBool _ _            =  Prelude.error "Unable to perform operation."

-- Evaluate Boolean operations with Booleans
evalBool :: KDLMap -> Exp -> Bool
evalBool _ (Lit n)         =  kdlboolToBool n
evalBool k (Variable n)    =  kdlboolToBool $ searchVariable' n k
evalBool k (e :&&: f)      =  evalBool k e && evalBool k f
evalBool k (e :||: f)      =  evalBool k e || evalBool k f
evalBool _  _              =  Prelude.error "Unable to perform operation."
```

For more information, hit me up. I will provide it on my github quite soon, so you can see more. But to answer your question, yes it's definitely possible.